# Sinatra custom Exception handling inside helpers not working

Tags: ruby, exception, jwt, sinatra

Im creating a middleware to protect specific routes in my sinatra backend application using `JWT token`. I moved the middleware code to a helper module so i can add it in routes that requires protection. The problem is when an `Exception` is raised. It ignores `rescue` in `begin` block.

When `JWT.decode` raises `JWT::ExpiredSignature` it doesn't fall in the byebug in `rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature` and not even in the `rescue Exception`. It goes straight to sinatra/base exception handling as `ERROR Rack::Lint::LintError: Body yielded non-string value [:status, 401]`. What's causing this strange behaviour?

my code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'jwt'

helpers do 
    def protected!
        begin
          byebug
          bearer = request.env.fetch('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').slice(7..-1)
          key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new ENV['PUBLIC_KEY']
          payload = JWT.decode bearer, key, true, { algorithm: 'RS256'}
          claims = payload.first # email, 
          if claims['iss'] == 'user'
            user = User.find_by_email(claims['email'])
            user = User.create({email: claims['email'], role: :user}) if user.nil?
            env[:user] = user
          end
            
        rescue JWT::DecodeError
          halt status: 401, message: 'A token must be passed.'
        rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature 
          byebug # does not get here
          halt status: 403, message: 'The token has expired.'
        rescue JWT::InvalidIssuerError
          halt status: 403, message: 'The token does not have a valid issuer.'
        rescue JWT::InvalidIatError
          halt status: 403, message: 'The token does not have a valid "issued at" time.'
        rescue Pundit::NotAuthorizedError
          halt status: 401, message: 'Unauthorized access.'
        rescue Exception
          byebug # not even here
        end
    end    
end



get '/test' do
    protected!
    
    response = { message: 'Hello world'}
    json response
end
```

stacktrace:

```
ERROR Rack::Lint::LintError: Body yielded non-string value [:status, 401]
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:21:in `assert'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:756:in `block in each'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:41:in `each'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:41:in `method_missing'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:754:in `each'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:41:in `method_missing'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:26:in `call'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:95:in `service'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
        /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/webrick/server.rb:307:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Where is JWT::ExpiredSignature defined? Are you sure that it's available within the Sinatra namespace, and isn't being handled in a gem or other module? Also, check the value of Sinatra's raise_errors configuration setting, which is only enabled in *test* by default.

Comment: You don't need the temporary variable `response`, you can just `halt status: 401, ...` and get it over with.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs its handled by 'jwt' gem. I forgot to add it in the question code.  I'll edit

Comment: `halt` doesn’t accept a hash like that. You need to do something like `halt 401, 'A token must be passed.'`. That will likely show you are actually raising `JWT::DecodeError` or `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError` rather than `JWT::ExpiredSignature ` since the lint error shows a 401 status.

Comment: thanks @matt . The halt parameters were wrong and causing this strange behaviour. i fixed it to "halt code, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, message" and it started working as expected. e.g.  halt 403,{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 'The token has expired.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 mistakes in the code.

1. Sending a wrong hash to `halt`. That raised an exception. the correct form is

`halt 403,{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 'The token has expired.'`

2. Exceptions orders were messed up because of Exception Hierarchy: `JWT::DecodeError` is a higher hierarchy then `JWT::ExpiredSignature`. A raised `JWT::ExpiredSignature` will be caught by `JWT::DecodeError`. In the end i changed my code to:

   ```
   begin

   rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature 
     halt 403,{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 'The token has expired.'
   rescue JWT::DecodeError
     halt 401,{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 'A token must be passed.'
   rescue JWT::InvalidIssuerError
     halt 403,{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 'The token does not have a valid issuer.'
   rescue JWT::InvalidIatError
     halt 403,{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 'The token does not have a valid "issued at" time.'
   rescue Pundit::NotAuthorizedError
     halt 401,{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, 'Unauthorized access.'

   end
   ```